# Parameters of OpenCV Mat::Mul

Tags: java, c++, opencv

Recently I was porting C++ code to Java. I found that the following C++ code compiles, but the correspondent Java code says it has problems.

- C++ code (compiles)

  ```
  void NormEveryRow(Mat &var1) {
      double normSum;
      int rowNum = var1.rows;
      for(size_t i=0; i<rowNum; ++i) {
          Mat Mi2 = var1.row(i);
          normSum = norm(Mi2, NORM_L2);
          Mi2 = Mi2.mul(1/normSum);
          var1.row(i) = Mi2;
      }
  }
  ```
- Java code (error)

  ```
  protected static void normEveryRow(Mat var1) {
      double normSum;
      int rowNum = var1.rows();
      for(int i=0; i<rowNum; ++i) {
          Mat Mi2 = var1.row(i);
          normSum = norm(Mi2, NORM_L2);
          Mi2 = Mi2.mul(1/normSum); // it expects Mat as a parameter
          var1.row(i) = Mi2; // 'variable expected' error
      }
  }
  ```

According to [OpenCV documentation (link here)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html), `mat.mul()` accepts `inputArray` as its parameter. So I was surprised when the first C++ code compiled. I guess C++ automatically somehow casted `double` into `inputArray`-compatible format.

Would you help me understand (1) why the C++ code compiles, and (2) how to make an equivalent Java code without errors? (I think `Core.multiply(Mi2, new Scalar(1/normSum), var1.row(i));` might work, but I'm not sure.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the error code say?

Comment: (1) mul (org.opencv.core.Mat) in Mat cannot be applied to (double) (2) Variable expected

Comment: In c++ it is able to accept a scalar (inputArray can cast into many things and it is checked in runtime if it is the type needed), however [in java](https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html) it only accepts Mat. Maybe the [function multiply](https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Core.html) helps, since it accepts a scalar as well, and it is the same operation (element wise multiplication). Also in c++ (not sure in java) you can do Mi2 = Mi2 * (1/normSum); or directly, Mi2 = Mi2 / nurmSum;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Mat Mi2 = var1.row(i);
Mat result = new Mat();
normSum = norm(Mi2, NORM_L2);
//advice: remember to avoid or not if normSum == 0.0
Scalar scalar = new Scalar(1.0/normSum);
Core.multiply(Mi2, scalar, result);
var1.row(i) = result;
```

There are other overloaded forms for multiply. See them [here](https://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/core/Core.html#multiply-org.opencv.core.Mat-org.opencv.core.Scalar-org.opencv.core.Mat-).

Edit:

Yes, the last line doesn't work in Java. Since the row(i) return just an alias to the original Mat data at position i, you should to use the slightly modified code bellow:

```
Mat Mi2 = var1.row(i);
normSum = norm(Mi2, NORM_L2);
Scalar scalar = new Scalar(1.0/normSum);
Core.multiply(Mi2, scalar, Mi2);
```

Comment: Thanks! May I ask a bit more? I tried to shorten the code in the for loop like: normSum = norm(var1.row(i), NORM_L2); Core.multiply(var1.row(i), new Scalar(1/normSum), var1.row(i)); It seems working but very slow, compared to C++ code. Is this a legit code, and is there any flaw which makes it slow?

Comment: Declaring Mi2 local variable performs better than call var1.row(i) several times. It is because the javac will actually create a variable to hold your calls to var1.row(i) even though you don’t explicitly declare them. In addition, the call lookup row(i) inside the object var1 will run several times instead just once. Thus, the code as first written should perform better than this last one.

Comment: I see. I was thinking in such a way that shorter code might run faster, which is not always true. Thank you for your clear explanation!

Comment: Oh, sorry for one more question. At the very last line, var1.row(i) = result;, Android Studio says "'variable expected' error". Is it forbidden to directly assign a value to var1.row(i) in this situation?